# How to reduce different lists to the exactly same length?

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I have some very big lists with different length. I want to reduce them all to exactly the same size (for example to 1000 elements)! I know there are kind of some "similar" questions, but I didn't find the coorect answer to my problem. So here an example what I did. For simplification we only use three lists here.

```
a = list(range(10000))
b = list(range(9879))
c = list(range(10345))

# Now I want to reduce all the lists to exactly 1000 elements
# I tried this approched like I read in some other questions:
aa = a[::len(a) // 1000] # len(aa) = 1000
bb = b[::len(b) // 1000] # len(bb) = 1098
cc = c[::len(c) // 1000] # len(cc) = 1035
```

But with this approache, the resulting lists have not the same length. How can I now randomly remove some elements of list bb and list cc to have also exact the length of 1000 elements? I don't want to just remove the last x-elements or the first x-elements.
Or is there a better solution to reduce lists of different length to the exact same length?

Edit: The order of the resulting lists (aa, bb, cc) should be the same as my original lists. I don't want to shuffle them randomly.

Comment: Have a look at `random.sample`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample

Comment: Do you want randomly to choose elements? Or to to take evenly spread element? (for example every 3rd element)?

Comment: @adirabargil I want to use evenly spread elements, that's the reason I tried with a[::len(a) // 1000], my resulting list should have the same order as my original list, just with lesser elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Accoring to the first comment your code would look like:

```py3
from random import sample

a = list(range(10000))
b = list(range(9879))
c = list(range(10345))

# Now I want to reduce all the lists to exactly 1000 elements
# I tried this approched like I read in some other questions:
aa = sample(a[::len(a) // 1000],1000) # len(aa) = 1000
bb = sample(b[::len(b) // 1000],1000) # len(bb) = 1000
cc = sample(c[::len(c) // 1000],1000) # len(cc) = 1000
```

note that the elements of aa are now shuffled

An non shuffled solution would be:

```py3
import numpy as np

a = np.array(range(10000))
b = np.array(range(9879))
c = np.array(range(10345))

# Now I want to reduce all the lists to exactly 1000 elements
# I tried this approched like I read in some other questions:
indeces = np.array(range(len(a))) ## make indeces
remove = np.random.permutation(len(a))[:1000] ## select indeces to remove
selected = np.in1d(indeces, remove, assume_unique=True) ## make list of indeces that are selected, faster on unique 
aa = a[selected] # len(aa) = 1000 ## select indeces

indeces = np.array(range(len(b)))
remove = np.random.permutation(len(b))[:1000]
selected = np.in1d(indeces, remove)
bb = b[selected] # len(bb) = 1000

indeces = np.array(range(len(c)))
remove = np.random.permutation(len(c))[:1000]
selected = np.in1d(indeces, remove)
cc = c[selected]  # len(cc) = 1000
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm using the non shuffled solution now :)

Answer (score 2):

you can use random.shuffle function so that you can take first x elements of the array.

```
import random
a = list(range(10000))
b = list(range(9879))
c = list(range(10345))

random.shuffle(a)
random.shuffle(b)
random.shuffle(c)

# Now I want to reduce all the lists to exactly 1000 elements
# I tried this approched like I read in some other questions:
aa = a[:1000] 
bb = b[:1000] 
cc = c[:1000]
```

Comment: Its a nice answer but see incomments, he wants evenly spread elements..

Answer (score 2):

I would just do as you did and then cut off the last elements.. it is impossible to spread the elements evenly without some extra element when the number cant be divided by
1000 so:

```
aa = a[::len(a) // 1000] [:1000]
bb = b[::len(b) // 1000][:1000]
cc = c[::len(c) // 1000] [:1000]
```

if you insist on not taking the out the last elements that left.. you can use after this above code the other answer and choose randomly..

Comment: Thank you for this answer. It helped me a lot, but I'm now trying to use the solution of Martin for my problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
import random
a = list(range(10000))
b = list(range(9879))
c = list(range(10345))


def randomm(x):
    while True:
        u = []
        r = random.randint(0,x)
        if r in u:
            pass
        else:
            u.append(r)
            return r

aa = [a[randomm(len(a))] for i in range(1000)]
bb = [b[randomm(len(b))] for i in range(1000)]
cc = [c[randomm(len(c))] for i in range(1000)]
```

I created a container for the random generator, so that number is repeated.